# Selecting from one MySQL table, return count(id) even if count is 0

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I've been scouring google for the answer to this, and I'm SURE it's easier than I'm making it, and I'd like to learn the right way to do this.

I have one table `emails_sent` that I'm selecting counts from and grouping by a column.  Each row has one of 3 `type` - "confirm", "1day", and "sameday".  I'm also doing this by a certain date.  So let's say, here's an example query I'm selecting for today:

```
SELECT Count(id) AS count, 
       type 
FROM   emails_sent 
WHERE  Date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-29' 
GROUP  BY type 
ORDER  BY type;
```

This is what it returns:

```
+-------+---------+
| count | type    |
+-------+---------+
|    32 | confirm |
|     4 | 1day    |
+-------+---------+
```

Which is great, but there is also a third "type" that happens to have 0 records for today, but I need it to pull that count even if it's 0.

I've also tried creating a 2nd table with just those 3 "types" in it, and using a right join, but it still won't pull the 0 count.  This is what I did with the two tables:

```
SELECT t.type, 
       Count(s.id) AS count 
FROM   emails_sent s 
       RIGHT JOIN email_types t 
               ON s.type = t.type 
WHERE  Date_format(s.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-29' 
GROUP  BY t.type;
```

I'm sure it's just something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: There is no way to add a row to a query that does not exist.  The only solution in the SQL side would be to have a table of all of the values you expect, and to join to that.  One solution might be to select all of the unique values of type and then join that to a subquery aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t.type, 
       COALESCE( Count(s.id), 0 ) AS count 
FROM   email_types t 
       LEFT JOIN email_sent s 
               ON s.type = t.type 
WHERE  Date_format(s.date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-03-29' 
GROUP  BY t.type;
```

Note: I have used a `LEFT JOIN` instead, as `1 type has many emails`

Comment: This query pulls the data correctly, but still isn't showing a count of 0 for the other `type`.

Comment: @ryes31 Yes, it shall show it as `0` there's no emails available for it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, couldn't you just assume that if you didn't get a record for a certain type then that is because there is 0 entry?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but I'd rather have it pull the count from my initial query, instead of having to add in more PHP code to account for any email types that are missing.  I know I can do it that way, but I feel like I may as well learn it the right way from the beginning :)

Comment: Look at Bailey S' comment.  You can't add a query that doesn't exist.  You can do it with PHP code, but you would still need to query for all the "types" and see which are missing.  Some people may not agree, but I think reporting should be handled, in your case, in the PHP side.  You query what you can, and base your report on that using a choice of scripting language.